# Popover with MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Try to use bootstrap popover with MeteorJS and have 2 troubles:

1. Can't assign some value that coming from collection to input value
2. I try to get one popover on `html,body` but have every popover on every template, it's normal, but I try to do only 1 popover on 1 screen

I have collection `Posts`  with such documents `Posts.insert({title:"Loli Pop"});`

> ```
> Meteor.publish("posts_levels", function(){
>     return Posts.find();
> });
>
> <template name="www">
> {{#each level}}
>    {{> one}}
> {{/each}}
> </template>
>
> Template.www.onCreated(function(){
>   var self = this;
>   self.autorun(function() {
>       self.subscribe('posts_levels');
>   });
>  });
> ```

---

> ```
> <template name="one">
>     <div class="popover-markup">
>         <div class=" trigger ">
>             Edit
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="content-popover hide">
>         <form class="form">
>             <input name="title" id="post_edit_title" value="{{title}}" />
>         </form>
>     </div>
> </template>
> ```

---

> ```
> Template.one.onRendered(function(){
>     $('.popover-markup > .trigger').popover({
>     html : true,
>     content: function() {
>         return $('.content-popover').html();
>     },
>     container: 'body',
>     placement: 'right'
> });
> ```

**EDIT:** 2 problem solved for 50%, I add this, and now it's hide when I open another popover, but then I must click 2x on `.trigger` to show new popover

```
$('.popover-markup > .trigger').popover({
    html : true,
    content: function() {
        return $('.content-popover').html();
    },
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right'
    }).on("click", function(e){
        $('.trigger').not(this).popover('hide');
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest to ask 2 questions. And tell us what you already found that is not working. And it looks like not all the code is in your question to understand to problem. You mention a collection that we don't see in your question.

Comment: @josharink I will edit this question, 1 min

Comment: @josharink Done! It would be great if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an anwser for your question 1 (assign value from collection to input).

The input in the template gets the value of title. When you remove the `hide` class you can see the title from the collection. But a popover inserts new elements into the DOM. And those new elements are rendered by Bootstrap and not rendered by Blaze, so the input is not filled with the value of `title`.

What you can do is attach an event handler to the popover when it is shown. Something like this:

```
Template.one.onRendered(function(){
$('.popover-markup > .trigger').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $('.content-popover').html();
        },
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'auto top'
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        $('.popover-content #post_edit_title').val(this.data.title);
    }.bind(this));
});
```

As you can see the event `shown.bs.popover` can be used to do some initialization. In the event handler the value for the input is set. 
It is important to have the jquery selector find your input in the popped form, that's why the selector starts with `.popover-content`. Otherwise it would set the value to the first input that was defined in the template.

Another thing to note is the use of `bind(this)`. That attaches `this` and makes it usable inside the event handler so you can get the value of title.

BTW, there is also a `hidden.bs.popover` event when the popover is closing.